# Variable scope and testing with qUnit

Tags: javascript, scope, qunit

I'm new to qUnit testing and having trouble to understand why my variable "a" passes a scope test, even if the test is called before "a" was defined. When I log out "a" it behaves as expected. Can anyone give me a hint?

Here's the code:

```
function outer() {
    test('inside outer', function (assert) {
        assert.equal(typeof inner, "function", "inner is in scope"); //pass
        assert.equal(typeof a, "number", "a is in scope"); // pass
    });
    console.log(a); // undefined
    var a = 1;
    console.log(a); // 1
    function inner() {}

    var b = 2;

    if (a == 1) {
        var c = 3;
    }
}

outer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of JavaScript's [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) "a" is really declared at the top of your function but is initialized at the point in your code where you assign it a value.

So, when your code is interpreted, it actually looks more like this:

```
function outer() {
    var a, b, c;
    test('inside outer', function (assert) {
        assert.equal(typeof inner, "function", "inner is in scope"); //pass
        assert.equal(typeof a, "number", "a is in scope"); // pass
    });
    console.log(a); // undefined
    a = 1;
    console.log(a); // 1
    function inner() {}

    b = 2;

    if (a == 1) {
        c = 3;
    }
}
```

Also, take a look at JavaScript's function scoping rules: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. In the article you've linked it says that declarations are hoisted but initializations are not (Just like in your rewritten code). But shouldn't "typeof a" be rather "undefined" then?

Comment: I agree it is confusing that it would not be "undefined" at that point in the the code execution. I am under the impression that qunit's "test" function is synchronous so it shouldn't have been given the "number" type at that point.